# CS50 pset 3: Tideman sort_pairs function

Tags: quicksort, cs50

I need some assistance in understanding the logic behind this function. This is my current sort_pairs function in Tideman:

```
// Sort pairs in decreasing order by the strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    qsort(pairs, pair_count, sizeof(pair), compare);
    return;
}

// Function for sort_pairs
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const pair *p1 = (const pair *) a;
    const pair *p2 = (const pair *) b;
    if (p1->winner < p2->winner)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (p1->winner > p2->winner)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This does not clear check50 and I looked online to find how to approach this problem. It seems that most functions compare the values from the preferences array instead (eg `preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser]`) . My previous functions vote, record_preferences, and add_pairs all clear check50. I have not advanced beyond sort_pairs yet.

Why can't I compare the strength of victory directly from the pairs array instead since I already have the data stored there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make this so complex, you can use your own sorting here. Let's try a simple insertion sort-

```c
void sort_pairs()
{
    pair temp;
    for (int i = 1, j; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        temp = pairs[i];
        j = i - 1;
        for (; j >= 0 && preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] < preferences[temp.winner][temp.loser]; j--)
        {
            pairs[j + 1] = pairs[j];
        }
        pairs[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

The `pair` struct looks like-

```c
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;
```

Explanation:-

- We go through each pair of elements inside the `pairs` array - starting at `1` since I'm going to compare with the *previous* element (`j = i - 1`)
- Now we check all the previous elements from the current element and compare them with the key - `preferences[pairs[INDEX].winner][pairs[INDEX].loser]`

  This is the key you should be sorting by. `preferences[WINNER_ID][LOSER_ID]` means the *amount of people that prefer `WINNER_ID` over `LOSER_ID`*.

And that's pretty much it!, it's simply a insertion sort but the *key* is the important part.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it really helped.
 
I would like to clarify one more thing: this sort function will result in the highest value of pairs[j].winner being the first in the array of pairs. In this case will pairs[j].loser need to be even considered?
Can I simply sort by only looking at the values of pairs[j].winner and sort in decreasing order? I did this previously and the function cleared check50, would like to know if it is an alternative solution.

Comment: @Alwin actually you need to consider both because you're supposed to sort by *strength of victory*. So you're supposed to consider the *difference* between the winner and loser. Check50 might have passed because it's not very exhaustive

Comment: It just occurred to me that if two candidates had the same values for winner but different for the loser then the sorting function I suggested would not work as it does not look at the loser values at all. Thanks for the help once again